# Python returning to a class atribute

Tags: python

The code does not alter `uppertank.cap` and `lowertank.cap` prints at the end of the code. when running function `drain` and returning `a, b`. How do I get the values attached to the class attributes passed to `drain` returned

```py
class Tank:
    def __init__(self, cap):
        self.cap = cap

    uppertank = Tank(70)
    lowertank = Tank(10)

    print("uppertank", uppertank.cap)
    print("lowertank", lowertank.cap)

    def drain(b, a):
        b = a + b
        a = 0
        print("drain", a)
        print("drain", b)
        return a, b

    drain(uppertank.cap, lowertank.cap)
    print("uppertank", uppertank.cap)
    print("lowertank", lowertank.cap)
```

Comment: Why do you think this *should* change those caps?

Comment: If `drain` is intended to move values between two `Tank` instances, I'd expect it to be `def drain(b: Tank, a: Tank) -> None:`.

Comment: scott returning the values to the 2 tanks

Answer (score 0):

im not positive what youre asking but  if you want to set the uppertank.cap or lowertank.cap you do

uppertank.cap = "new value1"
lowertank.cap = "new value2"

if you do that maybe it will work also the function doesntneed to return since its not being assigned to any value